# Moq setup method did not override the previous setup method, leading to verification of unneeded method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

in `[TestInitialize]` I wrote

```
dbfc.Setup(_=>_.crt(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("blhblh");
```

That because i need it in many tests.

now, at the `[TestMethod]` itself I wrote

```
dbfc.Setup(_=>_.crt("blhblh")).Returns("blhblh").Verify;

dbfc.VerifyAll();
```

The result is that the first method went through verification, even though I didn't want it to, and I got an error because of the first method, and I want the second one to override the first, and that only the second will undergo verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mock is to be specific for each test method you write, then instantiate and set up the mock right at the spot where you want  as in

```
dbfc = new Mock<Class/Interface>();

dbfc.Setup(_=>_.crt("blhblh")).Returns("blhblh").Verifiable();

dbfc.VerifyAll();
```